# Why does this event handler in RaphaelJS, run straight away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, raphael

Why does this event handler in RaphaelJS (2.0.0) run straight away and not when you click on it?

```
function enlarge (shape) {
  shape.animate({'transform' : 's2'}, 200);
}

jQuery(function () {
  var paper = Raphael("canvas", 1000, 1000);
  var button = paper.circle(300, 50, 20);
  button.attr({'fill':'black'});

  var circle = paper.circle(50, 50, 20);
  circle.attr({'fill':'red'});

  button.mousedown(enlarge(circle));
});
```

Comment: Fyi, if you replace `jQuery(function () {` with `jQuery(function ($) {` you can use `$` inside that function instead of having to write `jQuery` all the time. (even though in your case it doesn't matter since you aren't using it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.mousedown()` expects a function reference as its argument.  Instead, you are *calling* a function, and all `.mousedown()` gets as its parameter is `undefined`. Since you need to pass `circle` to `enlarge()` you can't pass a reference to `enlarge` directly.  Instead, wrap your call to `enlarge()` in a function:

```
button.mousedown(function () {
    enlarge(circle);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you *call* it straight away.

Replace `button.mousedown(enlarge(circle));` with this code:

```
button.mousedown(function() {
    enlarge(circle)
});
```